# Drools Workbench | Cloning a local Repo Gives "Invalid remote: origin"

Tags: git, github, drools, workbench

I am trying to clone a repo in Drools WorkBench and getting the following error

*"Can't clone repository. java.lang.RuntimeException:Invalid remote: origin"*

The repository which I am cloning, resides in my local machine. Following are the inputs I am providing to WorkBench clone Wizard,

"Repository Name = repoCloned"
"Organizational Unit = inTech"

"GIT URL = file:///D:/Servers/Drools-6-Deployment/repo/repoA.git"

"User Name = " (Currently I am giving my github account cred. What to give in user name?)
"Password = " (Currently I am giving my github account cred. What to give as password?)

Why am I getting remote origin error when I am cloning from a local GIT repository ?

kindly let me know what to give as *User Name* and *Password* when I am cloning from an existing git repo in my local filesystem.

Comment: Try not giving a username/password, to be sure they won't be passed to the url. If that doesn't work, keep those fields empty and try an url like `/D/Servers/Drools-6-Deployment/repo/repoA.git`, to see if that works better.

Comment: @VonC. Still getting the same error. Do I need to define/configure remiote for my git repository, repoA.git

Comment: "Why am I getting remote origin error when I am cloning from a local GIT repository ?" any clone (local or not) adds a remote named "origin". If, in the new clone, a `git remote -v` doesn't list origin, then indeed, try and add one manually: `git remote add origin /D/Servers/Drools-6-Deployment/repo/repoA.git`

Comment: Still getting the same error may be because of the bare repository.

Comment: Note: the remote is supposed to be a bare repo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309