# concept of bare shared repository in git

Tags: git, repository, git-bare

I have been facing difficulty in understanding the bare repository . I have read everywhere that a shared repo is a bare repo. Why must it be a bare repo? Can't it be a normal repo which collaborators clone and then push/pull?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the -practical- difference between a Bare and non-Bare repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be a bare repo because a not bare repo would have a working tree (meaning a specific version of that repo checked out and with files visible).

Each time you are pushing to a non-bare repo, you have no guarantee that its working tree will reflect what you are pushing, since by default said working tree will be untouched.
(Imagine if a push would trigger an update of the working tree: the files would change all of a sudden without any control from users on the receiving end)

That is why it is simpler to have a bare repo as an upstream repo (one you push to): no working tree to manage/update.

See more at "[all about "bare" repos -- what, why, and how to fix a non-bare push](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html)".

> It doesn't have a checked out tree, so it just does what the "server" notionally does in a centralised VCS -- records commits, branches, etc when you push to it, and gives you the latest versions when you clone or pull from it.

Comment: can you please explain this a bit if possible?"Each time you are pushing to a non-bare repo, you have no guarantee that its working tree will reflect what you are pushing, since by default said working tree will be untouched."

Comment: @user2636464 when you push new commits, the files that are currently checked out won't change.