# When to use a bare Git repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

What are some use cases for a bare Git repository?

When should we prefer to use a bare repository and what benefits it gives us?

If I need a repository for sharing with a team and pulling changes from production server should I use a bare Git repository?

Comment: You'd use a bare repository when you don't plan to directly edit any files in this repository.

Comment: Example of indirect editing: another repository pushing changes to this repository.

Comment: My use case would be git deployement on a server.

I create a bare repository where I push local changes,then I had a post commit hook to the bare repo that will checkout the bare repository and push the code to the app directory of my server.A bit like heroku or openshift deployement.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309.

Answer (score 2):

My main use case for a bare Git repository is for a repository I can push my local changes into.  It's usually (though not always) on a remote server.

Comment: Can a working tree be completely reconstructed from a bare repo?