# Location of the source files on the GitLab machine?

Tags: gitlab

Im running a self hosted GitLab on a Ubuntu Server 14.04. I've installed it with this guide https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-9-stable/doc/install/installation.md.

I've pushed a git repo to the GitLab server from another machine.

Where can i find the source files for this repo on the server machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repos are stored as **[bare repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)** in a path defined in [`config/gitlab.yml.example#L210-L212`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/a338954c331ed451c7b7dd39b28b9649dfca26ba/config/gitlab.yml.example#L210-L212):

```
# REPOS_PATH MUST NOT BE A SYMLINK!!!
    repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
```

By default: `/home/git/repositories/`

Again, those are bare repos, meaning repositories without working tree: you won't find source files there, only repo to which you can push to (because they don't have working tree to synchronize)