# error when cloning git repository with ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I set up a git repository in a directory named `ABC3` on my remote server `public_html/ABC3`.

```
git init
```

I want to clone the repository to my local computer. Here's what I do: cd into the directory where I want to work, say `Desktop/GitFun`, then I attempt to clone with the following command

```
git clone myusername@myserver.com:/public_html/ABC3.git
```

After entering my password I get back the error

```
fatal: '/public_html/ABC3.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Am I doing it right? ABC3 is the name of the directory, right?

Probably important: I'm working with a Bluehost shared server. On their site they mention installing GIT on a VPS or private server, but nothing about it on the shared server. When I `git --version` I get a positive response, 1.7.11.3. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have created a non-bare repo, the url should have been:

```
git clone myusername@myserver.com:/public_html/ABC3
```

I would recommend creating a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)** though (as [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGmzNwT0gK4)):

```
cd /public_html
git init --bare ABC3
```

Then the url would be indeed:

```
git clone myusername@myserver.com:/public_html/ABC3.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer could be useful for others whose git repository is not in `public_html`

If you created your bare repo here:

```
cd ~
mkdirs git/myapp.git
cd git/myapp.git
git init --bare
```

You can try (note the use of `~` instead of `/home/myusername`)

```
git clone myusername@myserver.com:~/git/myapp.git
```

If this still does not work, I also incorporated suggestions from [here](http://www.calzzani.com/blog/?p=92) and [here](http://www.gongey.com/archives/setup-git-repository-on-bluehost)