# git diff on a bare repo

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

I wanna see how much a repo changed in the last month on gitlab server side

```
cd /path/to/my/bare/repo.git/
git --git-dir . diff --shortstat "@{1 month ago}"
fatal: Unable to read log 'logs/refs/heads/master': No such file or directory
```

However it works fine in local checkout-ed working branch.

Is there a way to do this without too much hassle?

To avoid X-Y problem: I wanna run statistics through hundreds of repos on a Gitlab server

Comment: Did you try in the repo directory without `--git-dir` ?

Comment: `cd /path/to/bare/repo.git ; git diff --shortstat '@{1 month ago}'` should work.

Comment: What does `git --git-dir /path/to/my/bare/repo.git/ branch -a` states?

Comment: @NoDataFound yes. @knittl same error as my question. @marbu shows `* master`

Comment: Simply running git diff on a bare repository give me this: `This operation must be run in a work tree`. I would not say it's not possible (gitk shows diff on bare repo but I guess it uses the SHA1 of commits to create the diff!).

Comment: @NoDataFound That's what I guessed. I did a simple `strace git log` , it is indeed scanning through lots of SHA1, but `git diff` requires `logs/refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and make sure, when diff'ing in a bare repo, to specify two commits (or diff would default to the working tree, which doesn't exist in a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)**).

You don't need `--git-dir .`

However, using **date** when [specifying a revision](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions) wouldn't work, as it is based on `logs/refs`, which doesn't exist in a bare repo

```
<refname>@{<date>}, e.g. master@{yesterday}, HEAD@{5 minutes ago}
```

> A ref followed by the suffix @ with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{yesterday}`, `{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}` or `{1979-02-26 18:30:00}`) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time.
>   **This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`)**.

Comment: thanks, any solution to grab statistics? So far my best effort is to list out number of commits using `git log` but it's not as good as `git diff --shortstat`

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I was getting `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

If you are getting the error (in your bare repo):

```
[ec2-user@xxxxx git]$ git diff 81dcb182e4d16b6894b69a5b31133b8d8ff6c5e2
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Ensure you are providing **two** commit hashes to diff.(as HEAD is a symbolic ref)

```
[ec2-user@xxxxx git]$ git diff <BASE COMMIT HASH> <UPDATE COMMIT HASH>
```

Eg.

```
[ec2-user@xxxxx git]$ git diff 11dcb182e4d16b6894b69a5b31133b8d8ff6c5ex 81dcb182e4d16b6894b69a5b31133b8d8ff6c5e2
```