# fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree on pre-receive hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks, git-diff

In the process of [pre-receive](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_file_extensions.sh), I get the `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` exception while hit the `pre-receive` hook. I am sure the hook is hitting, Becasue I can print my own message by that hook.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILES=`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD~1`
for COMMIT in $FILES;
  do
      case $COMMIT in
      *.txt|*.pdf|*.docx)
        echo "Hello there! We have restricted committing that filetype.
        exit 1
        ;;
      esac
done
exit 0
```

Whether my hook code is wrong or any other issue? but [this hook](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_file_extensions.sh) is running perfecly.

Comment: maybe related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638767/git-diff-on-a-bare-repo

Answer (score 4):

`HEAD` (if it exists at all) will not point at what you expect in a bare repository (it points at the initial value for `HEAD` when someone runs a `git clone`).

From a pre-receive hook, you have to read the list of commit hashes from `STDIN` to know what commit you should look at :

> *from `git help githooks` :*
>
> **pre-receive**
>
> ...
>
> This hook executes once for the receive operation. It takes no arguments, but for each ref to be updated it receives on standard
>    input a line of the format:
>
> ```
> <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
> ```
>
> where `<old-value>` is the old object name stored in the ref, `<new-value>` is the new object name to be stored in the ref and
>    `<ref-name>` is the full name of the ref. When creating a new ref, `<old-value>` is 40 0.

So your script could do something like :

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

# read lines from stdin, assign first value to 'old', second to 'new',
#   third to 'refname' :
while read old new refname; do

  # use $old $new and $refname inside this block
  FILES=`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d $old $new`

  ...
done
```

Comment: Also note that the pre-receive hook will get all sorts of changes, so you may want to check to see if `$refname` is in `refs/heads` as opposed to say a new tag being pushed to `/refs/tags`

Answer (score -1):

git diff has two forms:

- with one commit diff between working tree relative to the <commit>
- with two commit diff between two commits

because on a bare repo there is no working tree, try to use

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD~1 HEAD
```

Comment: Indeed to fix the script this needs to review correct head, however the cause of error was really the use of git diff with only one commit