# How to clone repository including subrepositories at OpenShift?

Tags: git, openshift, git-submodules

I have public git repository containing some submodules. How can I configure my OpenShift setup to clone the repository with param `--recursive`? Is there any way to override this?

Right now, when I do any push and trigger deploy on my app, none of submodules is cloned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I auto-deploy my git repo's submodules on push?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695346/how-can-i-auto-deploy-my-git-repos-submodules-on-push)