# Can't make a hook work in bonobo git server

Tags: git, githooks, bonobo

I added [bonobo git server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) to a windows server so that i can store the repos of the  company projects in the server. I also want to make automatic deployments using git hooks. As bonobo git server is a web application i thought i couldn't use git hooks. I did some research and found out it is possible to run them. ([someone's blog](https://blog.dangl.me/archive/configure-git-hooks-on-bonobo-git-server-in-windows/) , [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323632/bonobo-git-not-firing-post-receive-hook#:%7E:text=Bonobo%20Git%20Server%20itself%20doesn,do%20it%20on%20the%20server.) which leads to [here](https://groups.google.com/g/bonobo-git-server/c/Eg5MOe9sYkc)). I created the hook but apparently it is not working.

My hook is stored at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories\test\hooks` with name `post-update` (no file type specified) :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo post-update
```

In my PC, i added the new remote using  `git remote add dev <url to repo>`

When i run `git push dev master` the changes are pushed to the server but the hook is not run.

I followed the [installation instructions](https://bonobogitserver.com/install/) from bonobo.

I'm not sure if the problem might be that  apparently i used IIS v.6 instead of v.8 to configure the app
(i'm not sure about this but i suspect that the version is the 6th)

[image]

The permissions `App_data folder` within `bonobo.git.server folder`
[image]

I opened IIS ,converted bonobo.git.server to an application and configured the authentication:
[image]

all of the above as specified in bonobo installation.

To see if what was wrong was the hook itself, i created a bare repo within my computer.
[image]

The result i get when pushing to the server using the same hook is :

[image]

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: Does that help https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks? And it should bei placed in .git/hooks/...

Comment: The hooks is positioned in the correct place, the problem was that my web.config file didn't the proper configuration

Answer (score 0):

The reason the hook was not working is that my web.config was not configured properly.

I changed all of the routes to absolute routes

Example :

Changed

```
<add key="GitPath" value="~\App_Data\Git\git.exe" />
```

To

```
<add key="GitPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Git\git.exe" />
```