# Alternative to terminal (gui) for creating remote git repos

Tags: git, user-interface, terminal

I use SourceTree as git client and i can not create remote repos with it. I would like to use app with some sort of gui so i can avoid creating remote repos in terminal. What are my options. I use mac os.

*Update: 
I would like to connect to our in-house git server.

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is the remote Git repo hosting service.

For GitHub, for instance, you can use [GitHub for Mac](https://mac.github.com/) to publish a new local repo to a new remote GitHub repo.

Not *all* hosting service provide that kind of feature though.
For an in-house hosting service, there is no direct way to create a repo through a GUI directly on the remote server with Git alone: that **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)** needs to be created on the server first, before the GUI can clone it on the client.

If you can install a local **hosting repo service**, like for instance **[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)**, *then* you create repio on the server through the GitLab GUI.

Comment: I see. Sorry i forgot to mention. (I have updated question too.) 
I would like to connect to our in-house git server.

Comment: @LukaMis ok, I have updated the answer. By "creating remote repo", you mean the `git init --bare` you have to do on the server?

Comment: @@VonC Yes git init --bare. I guess i need some sort of app that allows me to create and delete folders and repos on server with button of some sort instead of terminal. Something like gitstack for windows. Our in house server is linux and it has git server installed. Now i would like to connect to this server and be able to create folders and repos visually instead via terminal.

Comment: @LukaMis Ok, that sounds like what GitLab (https://about.gitlab.com/) can provide. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @@VonC We will give a gitlab a go and see how it goes. Tnx.